# ASP.NET Web site with Crystal report session not working in iis server 8 and above but working in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, session-variables, iis-8, crystal-reports-2008

I have an ASP.NET web application developed in VS 2008, hosted in IIS 7 and it is working fine, when I moved the code to Windows 2019 server IIS 10 the same code is not working with pop-ups.
On opening pages using windows. open the session variables are getting reset.

I would like to mention that this page includes a crystal report.
The crystal report run time is installed in the server as well.

Please assist.

The application was developed in VS 2008, on button client click system opens a page with a crystal report containing multiple subreports.
The report is not connected to the database directly but connects via data sets that are populated on page load.
After hosting the code in server , I am getting below error;

```
Logon failed. Error in File C:\windows\TEMP\Reportname{F8EE4295-91EE-476B-95A7-E950D05B41FD}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.
```

Here is the code used.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.CrvSingleGTINReport.SeparatePages = true;               
reportDoc.Load(reportFilePath);
ReportdataLoad (reportDoc);
CrvSingleGTINReport.ShowFirstPage();                      
}

public void ReportdataLoad(ReportDocument reportDocument)
{
DataTable Data;
if (Session["Data"] != null)
{
Data = new DataTable();
Data = (DataTable)Session["Data"];
reportDocument.SetDataSource(Data);
reportDoc.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Landscape;
CrvSingleGTINReport.ReportSource = reportDoc;                    
}           
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that is failing? Perhaps some IIS configuration information?

Comment: try to use the SQL Native Client driver

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by installing Crystal report runtime for 32 bit and enabling the 32-bit application in the App pool.
Also configured the ODBC 32 bit.

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.